# How to use m.domain.com with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

**How can I make *www.domain.com/mobile.html* show up as *m.domain.com* in the browser bar?**

My standard *index.html* file is in the root directory, so its adress is *www.domain.com/index.html*.

It uses javascript to redirect users to a mobile website at *www.domain.com/mobile.html*.

I just want it to show up differently in the adress bar, not change the actual location of the mobile.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work properly with an `.htaccess` file on my web server. Instead I used the folowing workaround instead:

the html index file at `www.domain.com` redirects mobile users to `m.domain.com` on detection of a `screen.width <= 1024px`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 1024) {
    document.location = "http://m.spotlightfoto.nl";
}
</script>
```

Only the mobile version of the index is located at  `m.domain.com` and is linked to all it's resources at the `www.domain.com` by adding a `<base href>` at the very top of the `<head>`

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com">
```

I'm posting this for future reference.
Maybe it's not the most efficient or lean way of doing this, but it does give the desired results. The downside would be the added request by first going to the regular `index.html` before redirecting the mobile user to the mobile domain.